# Extremely Slow Initialization for Imagemapster Map

Tags: javascript, json, imagemapster

I am trying to initialize a map layout based on squares that refer to an ibeam location. There are over 500 json objects in some cases and it causes the initialization of the map to take for ever, sometimes between 30 and 60 seconds. Here is the javascript code I am using to initialize it, is there any way to speed up this initialization to be usable? It is an asp.net site if that helps any. Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('img').mapster('resize', screen.width, screen.height, 0);
initialize();
});



function initialize() {
var ibeamid = '';
var status = '';
var redIbeams = [];
var yellowIbeams = [];
var greenIbeams = [];

$.each(json, function () {
    status = this['status'];
    ibeamid = this['ibeamName'];

    if (status.toUpperCase() == 'G') {
        greenIbeams.push(ibeamid);
    }
    else if (status.toUpperCase() == 'Y') {
        yellowIbeams.push(ibeamid);
    }
    else if (status.toUpperCase() == 'R') {
        redIbeams.push(ibeamid);
    }
});

var basic_opts = {
    mapKey: 'name'
};

var initial_opts = $.extend({}, basic_opts, {
    fill: false,
    stroke: true,
    strokeWidth: 2,
    strokeColor: '000000',
    configTimeout: 30000,
    render_select: {
        fade: false,
        //fill: true,
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    }
});


$('img').mapster(initial_opts)
    .mapster('set', true, redIbeams, {
        fill: true,
        fillColor: 'ff0000',
        staticState: true
        //fillOpacity: 0.5
    })
    .mapster('set', true, yellowIbeams, {
        fill: true,
        fillColor: 'ffff00',
        staticState: true
        //fillOpacity: 0.5
    })
    .mapster('set', true, greenIbeams, {
        fill: true,
        fillColor: '00ff00',
        staticState: true
        //fillOpacity: 0.5
    })
    .mapster('snapshot').mapster('rebind', basic_opts);
```